# Am I answering this Verlet Algorithm question correctly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algorithms

I want to compare the velocity Verlet algorithm with the ordinary Verlet algorithm for the particle in a harmonic (spring) potential.

I am given that mass $= 1$ and spring constant $k = 1$

The ordinary Verlet algorithm needs two positions to kickstart the simulation. Starting from the initial conditions $x(0) =−1,\  v(0) = 0,$ and the initial force $f(0)$, generate an expression for the position after the first time step $x(∆t)$ using the following equation:

$$x(t+\Delta t) = x(t) + \Delta t v(t) + \Delta t^2 a(t)/2$$

Once I have $x(0)$ and $x(∆t)$, ordinary Verlet should be sufficient to propagate the particle dynamics forward in time.

This is my thought process:

- $x(∆t)$ --> when 1 time step occurs, what is the change of the
  position?
- I know that $f(0)=m*a$ so $f(0) = -kx = 1$, $a(0)=1$,
  $F=-1$
- I started to break it down $x(∆t) = x(0) + ∆t*v(0) +
     \frac{∆t^2}{2}*a(0)$
- so $x(∆t) = -1+0+(∆t^2/2)$
- thus $x(∆t)= \frac{-∆t^2}{2}$

Please correct me if I am wrong, thank you in advance

Comment: Your calculation seems correct. But what exactly is the question?

As you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet), the two methods are related but not the same.
Maybe it would be useful to write a short numerical simulation and look at the plots?
If you want a formal approach, it could be better to compare how both methods are derived or how to show convergence...

Comment: Using the initial conditions generated in the previous step, I need to then implement the ordinary Verlet algorithm in my code to propagate the particle dynamics. So I believe I would just use the formula I found with my initial conditions and implement it.

Comment: Ok, I'm must admit that I'm not sure what the most truthful kickstart for ordinary Verlet is to compare it with the velocity Verlet. There are different conditions which one could imagine. Your's looks reasonable to me, but you could also come up with other kickstarts.
E.g.: Use the velocity Verlet scheme to kickstart the ordinary Verlet or use the exact solution for your problem as a kickstart. Just try it :)

Comment: I believe I made a math error, from second to last bullet point to last bullet point. It was -1 plus the t stuff and I just made the t stuff negative